# How to populate select list using recursive function?

Tags: php, laravel

On my Laravel app, I have a self referencing table ( terms)  as follows:

```
Id  Name            Slug         Parent
4   Home            home          0
5   Travel          travel        0
6   Beauty          beauty        0
7   Parenting       parenting     0
8   Cooking         cooking       4
9   Skin Care       skin-care     6
10  Hair Care       hair-care     6
11  Facial          facial        6
```

I need to populate a drop down box  showing the nesting relationship. I have created a self referencing relationship in term model

```
public function terms()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Admin\Term', 'parent');
 }
```

In the controller I have the following code:

```
$terms = \App\Admin\Term::where('parent',0)->get(); 

function buildT($terms, $level=1){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        return  "<option>". str_repeat("-", $level) . $term->name . "</option>";
         if ( count($term->terms)){
             buildT($term->terms, $level+1);
         } 
    }
} 

echo "<select>" . buildT($terms) . "</select>";
```

I understand that I am not coding rightly. I am not clear how to return the value of the recursive function. Would you please guide me to write the code so that the output is a select list ( dropdown list showing the nested relationship).

Comment: You mean optgroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to do something with the return-value of the nested function
2. You need to append the results, and not `return` them right away - instead append the text to a variable, and return that at the end. .

```
$terms = \App\Admin\Term::where('parent',0)->get(); 

function buildT($terms, $level = 1) {
    $result = '';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $result .= "<option>". str_repeat("-", $level) . $term->name . "</option>";
        if (count($term->terms)) {
            $result .= buildT($term->terms, ++$level);
        } 
    }
    return $result;
} 

echo "<select>" . buildT($terms) . "</select>";
```

Comment: It is working. I am getting it in the select list. There is a problem, only one child is get nested under the parent. The sub sequent children are not nested. For example, Laravel, Ada, Php are also the children of programming as Java. And hair care, facial are also children of beauty. https://snipboard.io/EDkPrL.jpg. Where should I edit the code?

Comment: What does `dd($term->terms)` actually return? Have you ensured that their parent-relation is set on the objects too?